# Need to connect an Azure App Web Service to an on-premise SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web Service App deployed to an Azure App Service that I would like to connect to an on-premise SQL Database running on my dev computer working from home.  I've established a VPN Gateway on the same Resource Group and setup SQL Server - Service Account User for the Web Service App to to connect with.  Connecting the VPN Client obtains the following IP Address of 172.16.254.2. Replacing the local server name with this IP Address or IP Address:1433 in the connection string is not working... I get Web Server App error HTTP Error 500.   My questions:

1. Is something else required like configuring a Firewall Rule to make the connection?
2. Is there a way to test an on-prem SQL Server DB Connection from Azure?
3. Should I implement a Hybrid Connector?  If so would that eliminate the need for the VPN Gateway and local VPN Client?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly more than one way to configure this but I was able to get it to work... I'll explain by responding to my original questions:

Answers to #1 & 3:  I setup a Hybrid Connection which does Not require a VPN Gateway... it is the Gateway.  If connecting to a single machine like myself, the computer name can be used vs. an IP Address. Note, I listed Port 1433 (SQL Server's default port) in the Hybrid Connection and hence did not need to include it in the SQL Connection String. The Hybrid Connection requires both Azure Configuration, within the App Service, and installing a Hybrid Connection Manager on the on-prem machine.

When I deployed the Web Service App the Azure App Service recognized the connection string saved in the appsetting.json file but did Not import all string parameters. In the Azure App Service/Configuration I edited the connection string by switching the Type from "Azure SQL" to "SQL Server" and added "Encrypt=False".

Answer to #2:  I was able to test the network connection by running "tcpping" in the App Service Console but this only confirms the network connection and not the database connection.  It took some trial and error to figure out I needed to add "Encrypt=False" to the connection string.  I'm assuming it's unique to my setup... I'm running SQL 2019.  Prior, running the service directly in Browser just returned a 500 Error so I'm still open to suggestions on how best to test an on-prem DB Connection from Azure.  Hopefully a "Test Connection" option is on the Azure App Service Dev Team's Roadmap.

Hope this helps.